# FastAPI хранение Pydantic model в redis

Tags: python, redis, fastapi, pydantic, pydantic-2.x

Пишу приложение на FastAPI.
Есть Pydantic model:

```
class Status(str, Enum):
    inactive = 'inactive'
    active = 'active'
    done = 'done'
    deprecated = 'deprecated'

class ShowTask(BaseModel):

    tsk_id: UUID
    title: constr(max_length=255)
    describe: str
    date_of_create: date
    status: Status

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            UUID: lambda v: str(v)  # конвертация UUID в str при сериализации в JSON
        }

        from_attributes = True
```

Хочу хранить данные в кеше redis. Использую библиотеку aioredis. Вот коннект:

```
redis = aioredis.from_url(
    settings.redis_url,
    encoding="utf-8",
    decode_responses=True,
    password=settings.redis_password)
```

И вот endpoint, через который получаем данные из базы и потом кешим

```
@task_router.get("/get-task-list", response_model=list[ShowTask])
async def get_task_list(
        skip: int | None = None,
        limit: int | None = None,
        db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)
):
    try:
        # Данные из кэша
        cache = await redis.get(f"task-list.{skip}.{limit}")
        if cache is not None:
            try:
                data = json.loads(cache)
                print(data)
                show_tasks = [ShowTask(**item) for item in data]
                return {
                    "status": 200,
                    "from": "redis",
                    "data": show_tasks
                }
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print("Ошибка при десериализации данных:", e)

        # Получение данных из бд
        task_list: list[ShowTask] = await service.get_multi(skip=skip, limit=limit, 
        session=db)

        # Сохранение сериализованных данных в Redis
        await redis.set(f"task-list.{skip}.{limit}", json.dumps(task_list))

        return task_list
    except UniqueConstraintError as err:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(err))
    except DatabaseError as err:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(err))
    except Exception as err:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(err))
```

Не могу получить обратно из кеша объект Pydantic model. В редис сохраняется строка с экранами. Пробовал использовать pickle, но при обратной распаковке выходит ошибка, что формат не соответствует utf-8. Как сохранять в redis питоновские объекты и получать их обратно?

Comment: "В редис сохраняется строка с экранами" - что это значит?

Comment: выглядит вот так: "[\"{\\\"tsk_id\\\":\\\"ba8e778f-1d07-40fd-94b4-0f424c576636\\\",\\\"title\\\":\\\"Redis\\\",\\\"describe\\\":\\\"string\\\",\\\"date_of_create\\\":\\\"2023-07-26\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"inactive\\\"}\". Появляется куча слешей

Comment: Декодируете [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61021183/4752653) или просто через json.loads?

Comment: просто через json.loads

Comment: список с pydantic model кодирую json.dumps и отправляю в redis. Потом данные декодирую json.loads и пытаюсь обратно получить список с pydantic model (вот тут проблема)

Comment: Версия pydantic, кстати, какая? 2 или более ранняя?

Comment: pydantic==2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимальный пример кодирования списка объектов в json строку и обратного декодирования:

```
# Код для pydantic >= 2.*
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel, TypeAdapter
from pydantic.json import pydantic_encoder


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


response_list = [User(name="name", age=123)]
type_adapter = TypeAdapter(list[User])

print(f"Исходный список {response_list!r}")

encoded = type_adapter.dump_json(response_list).decode("utf-8")
print(f"JSON строка: {encoded!r}")

decoded = type_adapter.validate_json(encoded)
print(f"Декодированный список: {decoded!r}")
```

Вывод:

```
Исходный список [User(name='name', age=123)]
JSON строка: '[{"name": "name", "age": 123}]'
Декодированный список: [User(name='name', age=123)]
```

То что получается в encoded кладете в redis. После получения строки из redis декодируете ее через type adapter.

---

Полный пример на вашем классе. `json_encoders` убрал, т.к. на Pydantic 2 выдается предупреждение, что этот ключ конфигурации удален:

```
UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'json_encoders' has been removed
```

но и без него все прекрасно работает.

```
from datetime import date
from enum import Enum
from uuid import UUID, uuid4

from pydantic import BaseModel, TypeAdapter, constr


class Status(str, Enum):
    inactive = "inactive"
    active = "active"
    done = "done"
    deprecated = "deprecated"


class ShowTask(BaseModel):
    tsk_id: UUID
    title: constr(max_length=255)
    describe: str
    date_of_create: date
    status: Status


response_list = [
    ShowTask(
        tsk_id=uuid4(),
        title="Some title",
        describe="description",
        date_of_create="2023-09-10",
        status=Status("active"),
    ),
]
type_adapter = TypeAdapter(list[ShowTask])

print(f"Исходный список {response_list!r}")

encoded = type_adapter.dump_json(response_list).decode("utf-8")
print(f"JSON строка: {encoded!r}")

decoded = type_adapter.validate_json(encoded)
print(f"Декодированный список: {decoded!r}")
```

Вывод:

```
Исходный список [ShowTask(tsk_id=UUID('c1f45979-7b2c-4751-9698-950c929a7aed'), title='Some title', describe='description', date_of_create=datetime.date(2023, 9, 10), status=<Status.active: 'active'>)]
JSON строка: '[{"tsk_id":"c1f45979-7b2c-4751-9698-950c929a7aed","title":"Some title","describe":"description","date_of_create":"2023-09-10","status":"active"}]'
Декодированный список: [ShowTask(tsk_id=UUID('c1f45979-7b2c-4751-9698-950c929a7aed'), title='Some title', describe='description', date_of_create=datetime.date(2023, 9, 10), status=<Status.active: 'active'>)]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)